# IntelliJ keyboard shortcut to turn text into a XML 'tag pair'

Tags: intellij-idea

I inadvertently used a shortcut key.It can automatically change the string into a label pair, As in the picture.

process:

1. [Enter the text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJibz.png)
2. Enter shortcut key.
3. [Generate .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75RVU.png)

But I can not reproduce. Does anyone know what this shortcut key is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default IntelliJ behaviour in a XML file (and a HTML file and maybe some other file types too):

- Enter some text
- Hit TAB
- IntelliJ turns the text immediately prior to the cursor into an 'tag pair'

For example:

- Enter `foo`
- Hit `TAB`
- IntelliJ turns `foo` into `<foo></foo>`

If you find that auto completion feature useful you might also be interested in the `html/xml` live templates. See `Preferences > Editor > Live Templates`. Here's a screenshot:

[image]